# Spring Security then deploy -> 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, settings

I am getting started spring MVC project.
I use to Spring security.

I added : (web.xml)

```
<i>


    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
        </param-value>

    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

and 
i added : pom.xml

```
<i>


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test4</groupId>
    <artifactId>test4</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>test4 Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--
              SpringFramework-context
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--
              SpringFramework-webmvc
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--
            SpringFramework-webmvc portlet
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--
             SpringSecurity-web
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--
             SpringSecurity-core
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--
            SpringSecurity-config
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <properties>
        <javaVersion>1.8</javaVersion>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
</i>
```

Finally added (security-context.xml)

```
<br>

<i>

    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="guest" password="guest" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
<./


<br>
and my folder structure is <br>
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlzsx.png
```

and  BUILD is SUCCESS..
But 404 error to this./..
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Explain what happens after you build. How do you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in **web.xml**:

```
 <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```

to:

```
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

And change this in **security-context.xml**:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</http>
```

Hopes its help.

Comment: no. Still it brings up a 404 error page. Still it does not.

Comment: do you have a @Controller that will response to address `/` in your system?

Comment: yes.



@Controller

public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView indexPage(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("index");
        mav.addObject("call", "gi");

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView hello() {

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("hello");
        mav.addObject("call", "gi");

        return mav;
    }

Comment: I cant fully help you cause you need to trace the exact problem in your web. If you found any error that can be shown, please show cause it can help the communities to solve the problem. See my edited answer for update.